# Find out how many SSH connections currently exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using a simple shell script on my Linux server which checks if an rsync job is running or if any client accesses some directories from the server via Samba. If this is the case then nothing happens, but if are there no jobs and Samba isn't used than the server goes into hibernation.

Is there any simple command which I can use to check if an SSH connection to the server exists? I want to add this to my shell script so that the server doesn't hibernate if such a connection exists.

Comment: You might want to take a look at your /var/log/auth.log to see who is currently trying to access your server via ssh. It's not easy to count the number of current connections.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scan the process list for `sshd:` .

Established connections look something like this: `sshd: <username>…`

```
ps -A x | grep [s]shd
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 8):

use `who` command

it gives output like

```
username  pts/1        2013-06-19 19:51 (ip)
```

You could parse that to see how many non locals are added and get their usernames (or there are options see `man who` for more info

gives a count of how many non localhost users there are

```
who | grep -v localhost | wc -l
```